# M2: Finding all configurable products that do not have a simple product connected to it

Tags: magento2

I have removed a bunch of discontinued products (simple products) through CSV.

Most configurable products still have a few simple products attached to it. However, for some, literally all simple products have been removed.

I'm looking for a way to generate a list of all configurable product sku's, that do not have any simple product attached to it. Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy below script on Root file and Run:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$sql1 = "SELECT entity_id, sku FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id='configurable'";
$result1 = $connection->fetchAll($sql1);

$configurableArray = array();
foreach($result1 as $r){
    $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM catalog_product_relation WHERE parent_id='". $r['entity_id'] ."'";
    $result2 = $connection->fetchOne($sql2);
    if($result2>0){}else{$configurableArray[] = $r['sku'];}
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($configurableArray);
?>
```

**Note**: Don't know how you have deleted products, because in Magento 2 if you delete all the simple products of a `configurable` product using `admin` interface then `configurable` product gets converted into `simple`.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the size of the array returned by the method `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\LinkManagementInterface::getChildren` over your configurable product. If the size is 0 then you can return your sku, if the size isn't 0, then your configurable product have childrens.

Answer (score 0):

you can find list of configurable product sku using below code. Hope this code help to you.

```
$productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

foreach($productCollection as $product){
 if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
      $children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
      if(empty($children)){
        var_dump($product->getSku());
      }
 }
}
```